# Getting error "Cannot open load file: No such file or directory: helm-config" suddenly after upgrading to MacOS 13.1

Tags: init-file, helm, projectile, helm-projectile

I recently upgrade my Macbook Air to MacOS Ventura 13.1. I also updated X-Code, command line tools, brew (upgrade and update). Now I'm experiencing issues with my `.emacs.d/init.el` and `.emacs.d/common.el` at the point it's trying to set up `helm-projectile`.

It seems like the error reported above was somewhat common around 2014 era, but here we are in the brand-spanking new 2023 year, and I'm trying to understand this enough to fix it.

My `.emacs.d/init.el` file in full:

```
;;; -*- emacs-lisp -*-

(setq default-frame-alist '((width . 200) (height . 70) (menu-bar-lines . 1)))
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/extras/"))

(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package) (package-refresh-contents) (package-install 'use-package))

(setq common-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/common.org"))
(setq local-settings-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/local-settings.org"))
(setq local-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/local.org"))

;;; local settings that need to be set *before* the common stuff
(if (file-exists-p local-settings-file)
    (org-babel-load-file local-settings-file)
    nil)

(org-babel-load-file common-file)

;;; local stuff that can come after the common stuff
(if (file-exists-p local-file)
  (org-babel-load-file local-file)
  nil)
```

The problem occurs around line `(require 'helm-config)`:

```
(use-package helm-projectile
  :ensure t
  :config
  (require 'helm)
  (require 'helm-config)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-z") 'helm-select-action)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-i") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
  (define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "s-p") 'projectile-command-map)
  (define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") 'projectile-command-map)
  (projectile-mode +1)

  (when (executable-find "curl")
    (setq helm-google-suggest-use-curl-p t))
  (setq helm-split-window-in-side-p t
    helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source t
    helm-ff-search-library-in-sexp t
    helm-scroll-amount 8
    helm-ff-file-name-history-use-recentf t)
  (helm-mode 1)

  (projectile-global-mode)
  (setq
   projectile-completion-system 'helm
   projectile-switch-project-action 'projectile-dired
   projectile-find-dir-includes-top-level t
   projectile-mode-line '(:eval (format " Prj[%s]" (projectile-project-name)))
   )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`helm-config.el` was removed in https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/e81fbbc687705595ab65ae5cd3bdf93c17a90743, you can just delete that line in your configuration.